# nginx not returning updated headers from origin server on conditional GET

Tags: nginx, cache

I have nginx and its cache working as expected apart from one minor issue.  When a request is made for the first time it hits the origin server, returns a 200 and nginx caches that response.  If I make another request I can see from the `X-Cache-Status` header that the cache has been hit.  When I wait a while knowing the cache will have expired I can see nginx hit my origin server doing a conditional GET because I have `proxy_cache_revalidate on;` defined.

When I check if the resource has changed in my app on the origin server I see it hasn't and return a 304 with a new `Expires` header. Some may argue why are you returning a new `Expires` header if the origin server says nothing has changed and you are returning 304.  The answer is, the HTTP RFC says that this can be done https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3.4

One thing I have noticed, no matter what headers are I add or modify, when the origin server returns 304 nginx will give a response with the first set of response headers it saw for that resource.

Also if I change the `Cache-Control:max-age` header value from the first request when I return the 304 response it appears nginx obeys the new value as my resource is cached for that time however the response header value is that of what was given on the first request not the value that I modified on the 304 response.

I am running `nginx version: nginx/1.10.1`

Comment: Do subsequent responses from nginx after the initial 304 return the correct headers or it only the first one that is incorrect?

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald no, all headers mirror the first response when the origin server returns a 304

Comment: Interesting, it's possible you've stumbled on a bug in nginx. I've always thought of 304s as implying that the response has not changed in any way, but as you point out, the actual spec does allow for it. This may be worth a question in the official nginx forums at https://forum.nginx.org/. Or if you can generate a reproducible test case, submit it their Trac at https://trac.nginx.org/nginx